# Functions - finding the domain

Tags: functions

**Question:**

> Consider the function: $$f(x) = \log(2x + 1) - \log(x - 3)$$
>   What will be the domain of this function?

I used two approaches to solve this question. Both approaches got me different answers. Consider that we do not merge the two $log$ together. As we know that the value inside a $\log$ should be greater than zero:
$$2x + 1 \gt 0$$ 
$$x - 3 \gt 0$$
From these two inequalities, we get that $x \gt 3$

Now consider that we merge together the two $\log$:
$$\log(2x + 1) - \log(x - 3) = \log(\frac{2x + 1}{x - 3})$$
We now know that the value inside the log has to be greater than zero. This can be in two conditions. Either both the numerator and denominator are positive, or both are negative.
Thus we get:
$$x \in (-\infty, -\frac{1}{2}) \cup (3, \infty)$$

This is perfectly valid when we simplify the expression. However, if we don't simplify, the interval $(-\infty, -\frac{1}{2})$ becomes invalid for $\log(x-3)$ as the value inside is negative. Which answer is correct?

Comment: It is the first approach, imo: you cannot apply properties of logarithms if the logarithms aren't well defined to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule $\log a-\log b=\log\frac ab$ holds only on the condition that $\log a$ and $\log b$ exist. So when you're applying that rule you're *implicitly* assuming $x>3$, and this assumption has to be combined with the condition for $\frac{2x+1}{x-3}$ to have a logarithm.

Comment: So basically we cannot simplify the logarithm if the value inside the logarithm isn't known to us?

Comment: @Gummybears: I don't understand what you mean by that. You can use the rule as soon as you know that $a$ and $b$ are positive. You don't need to know _which_ positive values they are.

Comment: Oh, okay then. And another question. What if the question was reversed? If it was a single logarithm given, should we have split it into two?

Comment: @Gummybears: Again, the rewriting is only valid when $a$ and $b$ are both positive. It doesn't say anything about what happens when one or both are 0 or negative. So, for example, $\log\frac{-3}{-42}$ exists even though $\log(-3)$ and $\log(-42)$ don't.

Comment: So what you are meaning to say is that the two functions will be different? Upon graphing, the two functions will obtain different graphs. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gummybears: I'm saying that the two expressions are only guaranteed to be equal when $a$ and $b$ are both positive. If they are not, the left-hand side will not be defined; the right-hand side may or may not be.

Comment: Well it is a function that I am talking about, so we can obviously graph the two functions. I am asking will the two obtain different graphs?

Comment: @Gummybears: You can only graph a function where it is defined. If you have two functions with different domains, they are different functions. The graphs will be different sets.

Comment: And remember that defining a function by just giving an expression without specifying what the domain is, is strictly speaking not meaningful. What the exercise here asks you to is to try to _correct_ for the error the person who defined your function made when he neglected to tell you which domain he had in mind. Therefore you either have to guess what the domain is, or arbitrarily decide that you believe that the domain the sloppy creator had in mind was the greatest _possible_ domain he could have thought of.

Comment: Hmmmm.... So it is incorrect to give a function without defining its domain. Is there any other case, except for logarithm, where such a situation occurs?

Comment: @Gummybears: It is _strictly speaking_ incorrect -- but common, and doesn't create any major problems when the reader can figure out a domain that makes sense in context. There are many cases of functions that are not defined on all of $\mathbb R$, such as square roots (not defined for negative numbers) or division (not defined when the divisor is 0).

Comment: I didn't mean where the domain isn't all the real numbers. I meant where the domain is different if we simplify the expression.

Comment: @Gummybears: See ADG's example of $\sqrt x-\sqrt x$. This is not defined when $x$ is negative, but if you let the two $\sqrt x$ cancel, you get $0$ which _is_ defined no matter what $x$ is.

Comment: Ohhhh... I see now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider whether the domain of this contains "-1":
$$y=\sqrt x-\sqrt x$$
Or if the following contains "2":
$$\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{x-2}$$

Comment: Hmmm.... I actually don't understand how that relates to my problem.