# Why $(x^3-8)/(x-2)$ is not defined at $x=2$??

Tags: calculus

The problem:

> $$g(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$
>
> Explain why $g$ is not defined at $x=2$.

My solution:

$$g(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x-2} = \frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{x-2}$$

The two $(x-2)$ get canceled $\implies x^2 + 2x + 4$.

--> This should be undefined at $x=2$, not really.

But if we don't change the function it is of course not defined at $x = 2$, because it would give us a $0$ (zero) at the denominator. That gives us infinity.

Please help, not if sure if I am on the right track.
Thank you very much

Comment: The expression $g(x) = (x^3-8)/(x-2) = (x-2)(x^2+2x+4)/(x-2)$ is not defined at $x=2$. Cancelling the $(x-2)$ is an invalid operation as you are effectively dividing numerator and denominator by zero

Comment: Related: [Why does factoring eliminate a hole in the limit?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/462199/409)

Answer (score 1):

you have understood the situation well.  The formula for $g$ does not give a value at $x=2$.    The formula is just undefined.  However, there's a unique way to extend $g$ to be continuous at $x=2$, which is by setting $g(2)=12$, as you noted. One quibble, though, is that having a $0$ in the denominator does not "give us infinity".

Language note: Most mathematicians ( in my experience ) would say that $g$ is defined at $2$.  While that's not quite correct, it's kind of a short hand for the above "unique extension".

Comment: I'm a mathematician who would *not* say that $g$ is defined at $2$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Noted.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the division operator on $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | b\not=0\}.$$
Using the rules of composition, you can see that
$$x\mapsto {x^3 - 8\over x - 2 }$$
is not defined at $x = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this function:

$$g(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$

does not have a value at $x=2$ because it is not continuous at $x=2$ (or you could say it has a removable discontinuity at $x=2$) as a result,

$$g(x) = \frac{x^3-8}{x-2} = \frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}{x-2}$$

is NOT true for $x=2$

It is NOT correct to say "The two $(x-2)$ get canceled" because we can't divide by $(x-2)$ when $x=2$.

The two functions above have different domains but the same limit value at $x=2$.

Some what a similar argument arises when some one says that if $\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{2}{x-2}$, cancel the (x-2) out to get $1=2$, again we can't cancel (x-2) out in the denominator when it is zero.

A graph for a function with point of discontinuity represent the y value with a small open circle. See for example:

[WolfarmAlpha plot of the function with a hole representing discontinuity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discontinuities%20%28x%5E3-8%29%2F%28x-2%29).

The following links talk about the same issue you have here:

[Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455579/why-do-fx-frac-x%C2%B2-1x-1-and-gx-x1-not-have-the-same-domain-o/1455583#comment2964553_1455583)

[Link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462199/why-does-factoring-eliminate-a-hole-in-the-limit)

Comment: What do you mean it's not continuous at $x=2$?  If you define $g(2) = 12$ then it is continuous

Comment: The function has no value at x=2 as is, but it has a limit as x approaches 2. So the two functions have the same limit but they are not equal. Maybe I should phrase this better.

Comment: In fact the term to use is probably is that the function has a "removable discontinuity" at $x=2$ as in here:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discontinuities+%28x^3-8%29%2F%28x-2%29

Answer (score 0):

You can only factor $ x -2$ in the numerator and make the division if $x\neq 2$. The function is not defined in $x=2$ because the division is not defined in this point.